# Upload image file to server node.js express axios

Tags: reactjs, file, express, upload, axios

I am stuck trying to upload and save an image file to my backend. I am using axios to call express API from react frontend.

Frontend run on port 3000
Backend run port 8080

```
export function updateSociete(data){
return dispatch => {
    // Init loading...
    dispatch(setLoading()) 

    console.log(data) // File data is populated
    axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}api/societe/update`, 
        { 
            data: data,
        },
        { headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'Application/json',
            'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {  
        return response.data
    }) 
    .then( societe => {
        // do something
    })
}
```

And the express backend

```
router.post('/update', (req, res, next) => {
    var data = req.body;

    console.log(data) // No file data here
```

If I try to set the header to multipart/form-data, I still have empty data. Something happens when axios send data object to the backend, the backend receives normal data expect file data.

When testing with postman, I receive all data file etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into formData.

You can try the next:

```
export function updateSociete(data){  
 return dispatch => {  
 // Init loading...  
 dispatch(setLoading())   

 console.log(data) // File data is populated
 const formData = new FormData(data) 
 axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}api/societe/update`, 
    { 
        data: formData,
    },
    { headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'Application/json',
        'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
 })
 .then(function (response) {  
    return response.data
 }) 
 .then( societe => {
    // do something
 })
}
```

P.S: Make sure you have this
    `<form onSubmit={you upload function logic}>
    ....
    </form>`

know more at [Using_FormData_Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: For now, i juste convert the file into base64, then send it to DB.

Comment: Great! But this will store the image on the server itself !

Comment: Where else should the image be store ?